# Trouble getting onchange in a select element to work

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I have some HTML and I can't get the `onchange` function to fire.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function goToDelete(){
            alert("test")
        }
    </script>
</head>
<form id="checkboxes" method="post" action="myurl">
    <select name="dropdown">
        <option />
        <option value="Delete" onchange="goToDelete();">Delete</option
    </select>
</form>
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The change event is triggered on the `select` element, not the `option` element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`onchange` is an attribute of `select`, not of `option`:

```
<select name="dropdown" onchange="goToDelete();">
    <option />
    <option value="Delete">Delete</option
</select>
```

Comment: If I have multiple options, each with a different intended function to target, is there a way to make that happen?  Or maybe make the function behave differently depending on what was clicked by the user?

Comment: @avorum you have to compare the current value of the select. (`if (... == "Delete")`)

Comment: delete is a javascript key word. try to avoid using it inside javascrpt

Comment: @GokulKav where's the problem when it's used only enclosed in quotes?

Comment: putting the onchange in the select produces no results either (with just the alert in the function still)

Comment: @avorum because `alert` != `alter`?

Comment: fixed it by removing a line importing the jquery library from google, don't know why that was relevant.

Comment: it could possibly be because i used the syntax <script src="..." />, who knows